# Calculate $S=3\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}-\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{20}+\sqrt[3]{25}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculate $$S=3\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}-\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{20}+\sqrt[3]{25}$$ $\color{red}{\text{without using calculator}.}$

Please help me, I can't find any solution to sovle it.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact (algebraic) solution?  Why do you think that there should be one?  Is an approximate (numeric) solution acceptable?  For the last two terms $\sqrt[3]{25}-\sqrt[3]{20}=\sqrt[3]5(\sqrt[3]5-\sqrt[3]4)$, which matches the first radical.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm looking for an exact solution. Let $a=\sqrt[3]5, b=\sqrt[3]2$ I have $S=3\sqrt{a-b^2}+a(a-b^2)-b$. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I don't think you will get a solution without using $5$ and $4$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3sqrt%28cbrt%285%29-cbrt%284%29%29-cbrt%282%29%2Bcbrt%2825%29-cbrt%2820%29) says it is $0$, so we can multiply by conjugates as we wish.  I think we need to find something clever to do with the $\sqrt[3]2$

Comment: I had good fund with your question! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let

$$s=\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]{20}-\sqrt[3]{25}$$

If you carefully square $s$, you find

$$s^2=9(\sqrt[3]5-\sqrt[3]4)$$

Note that $\sqrt[3]2\gt1$, $\sqrt[3]{20}\gt2$, and $\sqrt[3]{25}\lt3$, so $s\gt0$. Thus $s=3\sqrt{\sqrt[3]5-\sqrt[3]4}$, hence $S=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but how we know to let $s=\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]{20}-\sqrt[3]{25}$

Comment: That's a definition. The Idea here is to look at this term more closely, and to help doing that, you just give it a name – in this case, $s$ was chosen.

Comment: @DDK, I'd like to call it inspiration, but it's really just experience.  The key idea was to get rid of the square root, so it made sense to move those little cube roots over to the left hand side.  I didn't feel like writing them all down, so I called them $s$.  That way I knew the left hand side, when squared, would be $S^2-2sS+s^2$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing your experience. :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
(9+4\sqrt[3]{10})(5-\sqrt[3]{10^2})&=5+20\sqrt[3]{10}-9\sqrt[3]{10^2}\\
&=25-20+20\sqrt[3]{10}-9\sqrt[3]{10^2}\\
&=5^2-2\sqrt[3]{10}\sqrt[3]{10^2}+20\sqrt[3]{10}-9\sqrt[3]{10^2}\\
&=5^2-2\sqrt[3]{10}\sqrt[3]{10^2}+20\sqrt[3]{10}-2\times5\sqrt[3]{10^2}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}\\
&=5^2-2\sqrt[3]{10}\sqrt[3]{10^2}+\sqrt[3]{10^4}+2\times5\sqrt[3]{10}-2\times5\sqrt[3]{10^2}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}\\
&=(5-\sqrt[3]{10^2}+\sqrt[3]{10})^2
\end{align}
Hence $$(9+4\sqrt[3]{10})(20-4\sqrt[3]{10^2})=2^2(5-\sqrt[3]{10^2}+\sqrt[3]{10})^2$$
therefore
\begin{align}
\Big(\sqrt{9+4\sqrt[3]{10}}-\sqrt{20-4\sqrt[3]{10^2}}\Big)^2&=(9+4\sqrt[3]{10})+(20-4\sqrt[3]{10^2})-2\sqrt{(9+4\sqrt[3]{10})(20-4\sqrt[3]{10^2})}\\
&=9
\end{align}
or $$-3+\sqrt{9+4\sqrt[3]{10}}=\sqrt{20-4\sqrt[3]{10^2}}$$
or more simply with $\sqrt{20-4\sqrt[3]{10^2}}=\sqrt{\Big(2\sqrt[3]{5}\Big)^2\Big(\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}\Big)}$ we have $$\frac{-3+\sqrt{9+4\sqrt[3]{10}}}{2\sqrt[3]{5}}=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}$$

Finally let $u=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}$ and define $$f(u)=3u-\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{5}u^2$$with $\displaystyle u_1=\frac{-3+\sqrt{9+4\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt[3]{5}}}{2\sqrt[3]{5}}$ as a root.